# angularJS $resource cache refresh

Tags: angularjs, caching, resources

I have a table with pagination and the rows of the table are loaded by a $resource call. If I use the angularJS $resource cache, it works, but here is the problem:

When a cell is updated, how can I refresh the cache results? The same when a row is deleted etc.

Any help would be apreciatted. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to remove the cached request. Something like:

```
$httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
$httpDefaultCache.remove("http://localhost/link-to-my-resource-request");
```

I haven't tested it but it should work. Also keep in mind that you need the exact URL of the request including query parameters if provided.

Comment: The are some problems: For example if I sort the rows by name, and I change the row with ID 1 and then I go back to the rows without sort, probably I will go to a state that have been cached, but the row with ID 1 won't be update because the url won't be the same. (users and users?orderBy="name")

Comment: I'm thinking to caching EACH row by ID... although probably is not the best solution.

Comment: You can just remove all the possible URL's because it looks like you would know all of them. Or you can create a custom cache and have more control over it. I wouldn't cache each item on it's own I'm a  big fan of consistency between server and client and I think it's safer to just to another request to the server. Also I know Angular has some Ordering filters so you can only have 1 request to the server and order them on the client.

Comment: I know about the angular's ordering filters, but there is pagination and the other rows are loaded by a $resource call, so it makes no sense to use the filters you said I guess

Comment: Ok, than just go with removing those URL's from the cache ... that should solve your problems.